# Getting error during data upsert operation

Tags: data-loader

I am doing data upsert operation in my org. There are around 40k records being userted. But during the operation i am getting error as shown in below screenshot: 
[image]

My data loader settings are as follows : 
[image]

Comment: This issue seems to be due to network or proxy. Can you try inserting again and in data loader settings check the Bulk API box and make the batch size 2000, as the record count is more than 40K

Comment: The dialog box indicates  there is one error. What does say the error output file about it ?

Comment: @Hemant Jain  :Thanks for the prompt reply! I am getting this error only some times not all times. So i am not if it was due to some setting error then above error msg should be all time...which is not the case. I will try your suggestion nevertheless.

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO  Error is that last name is missing for a record. But that can not be the reason as sometimes with that error i am able to upsert other records.

Comment: Well then I bet for network problems as well... That won't explain but I would divide the file in smaller sets, even though that's not a funny job that could be the fastest solution.

Comment: hmm...That can one of the option. Although not faster and easier